# After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu no longer loads

Tags: boot, 18.04, 20.04, grub2

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20 by running the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
sudo apt --purge autoremove
sudo apt install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The download and installation seems to have gone OK, but in the end when it restarts it doesn't load Ubuntu. I have dual OS grub, Window works fine, Ubuntu doesn't. When I select Ubuntu I get:

[image]

How could I resolve this? It might be OK to roll back to the previous version as well.

Comment: Please translate your question to English which is the language og this sit.

Comment: Downloading the image and reinstallation.